# How to bind the lifetime of a shared resource object to the union of its users' lifetimes?

Tags: c++

I have a number of GUI widgets that all make use of the same shared timer object. I would like to have the first GUI object that comes into existence create the timer instance and later have the last remaining gui object take care of destroying the timer.

Is there an idiomatic C++ solution for this kind of problem?

#### Update

[Here is an attempt at a more generic solution.](http://ideone.com/UMLvt)

Comment: You mean like a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_Smart_Pointers)?

Comment: Or reference counting (in general) ?

Comment: @chrisaycock: This case seems to call specifically for a shared pointer (not just any kind of smart pointer). Another option might be to have all the widgets be owned by the same thing that owns the timer object. The "owner" object could then manage the lifetimes of the widgets and the timer, and make sure they match up appropriately.

Comment: Is your SharedResource supposed to be some kind of singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: I know that it looks like a singleton but I don't think it's really the same.

Comment: @EmileCormier: What the OP is asking for is not even remotely like a singleton.

Comment: @DeadMG Well, maybe very remotely then.

Comment: @StackedCrooked so you've now pasted some code that seems to work and do what you want so have you now found an answer based on comments and answer given?

Answer (score 4):

You could use an shared_ptr<> and the last object destroyed that holds the reference would destroy the timer. If you want to transfer ownership from the first GUI object to the last then use unique_ptr<>

Comment: Be aware that your updated solution is not thread safe, if that's a consideration.